# Переключение между аудио картами

Tags: c#, windows, аудио

Имеется в компьютере 2 звуковых карты: встроенная и еще одна в разьеме PCI-Ex. Можно как то на С# сделать небольшую программу, или лучше виджет для быстрого переключения между этими картами, а то надоедает постоянно заходить в Пуск-панель Управления-Оборудование и звук-Звук и назначать там нужную карточку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложная задача. Теоретически, до панели управления (**RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL** - это через коммандную строку) можно как-то достучаться, практически... Лично я сумел найти такую возможность только для с++ и то еле-еле. Можете попробовать.

[Launch control panel apps programmatically](http://weseetips.com/tag/control_rundll/)